# Finding Subset of a numeric vector having NA values in R

Tags: r

```
x=c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA).
```

Wanted the vector (2,NA,3)

```
y=c(NA,1,NA)
```

wanted the vector (1) then.

So wanted the subset of the vector having numeric values from start and endpoint.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's unclear what your logic would be in different situations, e.g. `c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA, 5)`

Comment: it should be (2,NA,3,NA,5). So objective is to get the whole vector between the first and last number in the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom function like below for subsetting

```
f <- function(v) {
  r <- range(which(!is.na(v)))
  v[head(r,1):tail(r,1)]
}
```

**Example**

```
> x1=c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA)

> x2=c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,3,NA,5)

> x3=c(NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA)

> f(x1)
[1]  2 NA  3

> f(x2)
[1]  2 NA  3 NA  5

> f(x3)
[1] 2
```

Comment: @SouvikChakraborty You are welcome! If you are happy with this solution, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks!